# Trying to run scrapy shell in terminal

Tags: python, macos, shell, scrapy

I'm trying to run the following command in my terminal:

```
scrapy shell www.example.com
```

Instead of the desired result, I get:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/shell.py", line 115, in fetch
reactor, self._schedule, request, spider)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-16.7.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 122, in blockingCallFromThread
result.raiseException()
File "<string>", line 2, in raiseException
```

Could anyone help me to get the scrapy shell command working properly?

Comment: Try adding the URL scheme (http or https)

Comment: Already did. Doesnt work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a bug with the latest version of scrapy and twisted.

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2461

I'll edit my answer as soon as it's resolved!